# Change Gsetting with script on Logout

Tags: bash, scripts, lightdm, logout, killall

### System

Ubuntu Raring Ringtail (13.04) from fresh installation.

### Purpose

Main: **Change gsetting (desktop wallpaper) with script on user logout.**

### What's I've Done : (carefully read)

I try to stop an application named variety ([this one](https://launchpad.net/variety)) **on Logout** that I've put my workarounds inside. Variety is an autostart app, so it just started everytime I'm logging in. Variety has a function `on_quit()` and `force_quit_thread()` that are called when the app process stopped. So, I added my python script line inside, that execute my real script (`normalize`). When I tried to quit variety normally, it does what I want! I though, when the system log me out, any process that I started should also be stopped. But then, I realized, it is not. So, I couldn't use this way.

This let me thing to use another way to kill variety process manually when I logging out. I have tried `~/.bash_logout` (I doubt it, because I know autostart does not run on bash); `~/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` (But, I'm not use gdm); `~/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (This one doesn't work either! How come?); pam_script / pam-script (I don't know how to work with it. Really different.)

### Happened

But, the problem comes when I try to log out my account. It neither execute on_quit() nor force_quit_thread(). And the log I captured from `~/nohup.out` see last line, here you are:

```
.... bla-bla ... [only see last line]
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 2] No such file or directory

(variety:15627): Gdk-WARNING **: variety: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
```

They lost available resources, right? **Not quit-ed** normally then and means, gsetting not changed.

### Details

1. Added script inside `quit functions`

   It is on `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/variety/variety/VarietyWindow.py`:

   ```
   bashCommand = "/home/abdillah/Toolbox/command/normalize"
   os.system(bashCommand)
   ```
2. Script inside normalize

   **Purpose**: changing wallpaper when variety quit.

   ```
   echo $(cat "${HOME}"/.self-log)"| normalize" > "${HOME}"/.self-log #append log
   wallpaper=$(cat /home/abdillah/.wallpaper)
   filename="file://"$wallpaper
   configname=${filename/'#'/"%23"}
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri $configname #the most important
   ```
3. LightDM config file

   The one that make me confuse is that in it's [documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM), there isn't a statement mentioned `session-cleanup-script`. It is deprecated?

   ```
   [SeatDefaults]
   user-session=ubuntu
   greeter-session=unity-greeter
   autologin-user=
   session-cleanup-script=/home/abdillah/Toolbox/command/logoff
   ```
4. logoff file contains:

   .self-log file still empty => fail

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo $(cat "${HOME}"/.self-log)" |fail? (OnScript)" > "${HOME}"/.self-log #append log
   killall variety
   /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/variety/bin/variety -q
   echo $(cat "${HOME}"/.self-log)" |Success? (OnScript)" > "${HOME}"/.self-log #log
   exit 0
   ```

### Question

When anyone think, above condition is very specific, just answer the following question.

1. How to executing script directly on logout (**CMIW** the ways above. If not, any suggestion please), or
2. How I can stop variety properly when I logged out? (So on_quit() called)

### Possible Solution

- Start variety with [StartUpApplication] `in bash` and use ~/.bash_logout script to stop. But, how?

Ok. its long. But, I try to make as clear as possible. Because out there, there are lots of question related with this that I've read.

Comment: I think that `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` might be a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not straightforward. It requires start of script at X login and waiting till the and of X session. Fortunately we have inotify and pid of gnome-session.

Variety process should already be killed properly at the time of script execution.

1. Install `inotify-tools` package.
2. Create or modify ~/.xprofile script and add to it following line

   ```
   sh .xlogout &
   ```
3. Create ~/.xlogout with following content

   ```
   FILE=/tmp/.ICE-unix/$PPID            # pid of parent = gnome-session
   sleep 10s                            # wait for $FILE creation
   inotifywait -qe delete_self $FILE    # wait for $FILE deletion = logout
   # your code goes here                # = on_quit
   # gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
   ```